# Date Difference in ASP.Net in Month

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

In ASP.Net when i calculate the month i think it gives sometimes 1 month addition and sometime one month deduction below is the example.

```
Dim LsMGetMonth as double
LsMGetMonth =DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, '10/21/2012', 6/1/2013')
```

But when i calculate manually it gives 7 month.

But the Days if i calculate then give 223, its correct, but above calculation for month give 1 month more instead of 7 gives 8

```
Dim LsMGetDay as double
LsMGetDay =DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, '10/21/2012', 6/1/2013')
```

But if i calculate manually 223/30 for months is 7.43 if round-off then comes 7 not 8

same as sql query also giving 8 month

```
select DATEDIFF(MONTH,'10/21/2012','6/1/2013')
```

Please help on this.

Thanks
Basit

Answer (score 0):

"DateInterval.Month is calculated purely from the year and month parts of the arguments" 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx